# TypeScript: Infer parameter values from constructor and use it as type checking on class method's parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript4.0

Not sure if this is possible, but I'm looking for a way to allow TypeScript to automatically infer a class constructor's argument values, then use the inferred values to type-check another parameter of a class method.

For example:

```js
class MyClass {
  // aim: to infer the string values from the rest parameter param2
  constructor(param1: number, ...param2: string[]) {
    console.log(param1);
    console.log(param2);
  }

  // param uses values inferred from param2
  classMethod(param) {
    console.log(param);
  }
}
```

The aim is to allow TypeScript to infer values from `param2` then apply it onto `classMethod`'s `param`. For example:

```js
const myClass = new MyClass( 0, 'a', 'b', 'c' );
myClass.classMethod('a') // shall be correct
myClass.classMethod('x') // TypeScript shall highlight this with red wavy line
```

I've tried using generic, but ultimately confused on how to infer values from generic `T` which extends a string array. For example:

```js
class MyClass<T extends string[] = []> {
  constructor(param1: number, ...param2: T) {
    // things
  }

  // how do I infer the array values in T?
  classMethod(param) {
    console.log(param);
  }
}
```

Perhaps I'm still lacking of some steps to correctly infer the values from the generic. Will this be possible? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't `T` be an item in the array, not the array itself (i.e. `...param2: T[]`)? Then it's just `param: T` and `'x'` becomes invalid: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVaBTAHgFywDsATGCPAJwEtCBzAPmgG8BYAKGmmAHtDyKArsDzcKACgAOYCmAC2ARgBc0QgNkAjLBQA00AHQGpM2QCZl6ANoBdAJTN2nTgHon0PAAsatCA+gBfdl8XaHduAHdoYm5oAEloGgAzLTd3LGhpGXhoADcwEAEsGBpodAB+X1BICFgsD25iSWk5cztWDkcePm4QLD0QblpG4xsAbl8Atgn2TvJoWSQUGABeFSwIhGQqsWgABl0AcjB9g-Vj6H3gfehR9nnNqD1KqBq6hsP9u2CIdzyQaE0uKIKFhhLcFlVHosXqE3jgPtBguh4BIsABlYDUCR4aDfX4hKi0dwgAnubEeKgwMJUDzQYHEaBhMDZLLEwhYdhAA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks **@jonrsharpe**, it was an oversight on my end on the generic part. I will mark this question as answered with your answer.

Here's the correct answer as written by @jonrsharpe:

```js
class MyClass<T extends string> {
  constructor(param1: number, ...param2: T[]) {
    // things
  }

  classMethod(param: T) {
    console.log(param);
  }
}

const myClass = new MyClass( 0, 'a', 'b', 'c' );
myClass.classMethod('a') // correct
myClass.classMethod('x') // error
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=79&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVaBTAHgFywDsATGCPAJwEtCBzAPmgG8BYAKGmmAHtDyKArsDzcKACgAOYCmAC2ARgBc0QgNkAjLBQA00AHQGpM2QCZl6ANoBdAJTN2nTgHon0PAAsatCA%20gBfdl8XaHduAHdoYm5oAEloGgAzLTd3LGhpGXhoADcwEAEsGBpodAB%20X1BICFgsD25iSWk5cztWDkcePm4QLD0QblpG4xsAbl8Atgn2TvJoWSQUGABeFSwIhGQqsWgABl0AcjB9g-Vj6H3gfehR9nnNqD1KqBq6hsP9u2CIdzyQaE0uKIKFhhLcFlVHosXqE3jgPtBguh4BIsABlYDUCR4aDfX4hKi0dwgAnubEeKgwMJUDzQYHEaBhMDZLLEwhYdhAA)